# As an independent researcher with a PhD, Can one publish papers on both humanities and science in reputed journals? Will it be bad or good?

Tags: publications, journals

As an Indian scholar with a PhD in literature, will it be viewed negatively  for an independent researcher to publish some collaborative papers in science and engineering domains? Even though I'm currently not working, I wish to be a humanities lecturer soon. I like publishing papers on different topics either individually or in collaboration. But besides passion one also needs to focus on real, tangible benefits which is Acadmic Performance Indicators or API score. ugc care (https://ugccare.unipune.ac.in/Apps1/User/LR/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FApps1%2FUser%2FWebA%2FCAREList) prescribes only publication in reputed journals. So I am slightly confused as to whether the papers published in different subjects and disciplines not help one in increasing their API score as per UGC guidelines? Will my labor and spending of time in publishing papers go in vain and just be a passion or will it bring me some benefit too? Coz

Comment: If the papers or good, why would it be negative? What is an API score or a UGC guideline, and do those matter for an independent researcher at all?

Comment: Do you want to do good and meaningful work or are you obsessed with some "score"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That link only brings me to a login page. Do you have some link accessible also to external people?

Answer (score 1):

In the field of research, you are completely free to write on anything. If you are able to write on multiple topics or subjects, congratulations.

Did [Bertrand Russell](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/literature/1950/summary/#:%7E:text=The%20Nobel%20Prize%20in%20Literature%201950%20was%20awarded%20to%20Earl,ideals%20and%20freedom%20of%20thought.%22) not get a Nobel Prize for Literature, though he was a known mathematician?